# I am facing Manifest merger failed can any one tell.?

Tags: android

Manifest merger failed: Attribute

```
provider#com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider@authorities value=(fintnessathome.cardioexcercise.firebaseinitprovider) from AndroidManifest.xml:766:13-86
    is also present at [com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-72 value=(com.fintnessathome.fintnessathomeapp.firebaseinitprovider).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to <provider> element at AndroidManifest.xml:764:9-768:39 to override.
```

I am facing this issue, I got the template from my friend and i want to make some changes in the android app, it's showing this error when I execute this program.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in the gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX=true 
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=false
```

Also, add the following code into your manifest file inside the application tag

```
tools:replace="android:supportsRtl,android:allowBackup,icon,label"
```

Comment: after adding following in gradle.properties file

android.useAndroidX=true 
android.enableJetifier=true  

its shows following error
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
   > Cannot parse project property android.useAndroidX='true ' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around True, it's expecting a boolean rather than a String 
 `android.useAndroidX='true '`

Comment: i did removed but still same issue found

Comment: add the following to the Gradle and run gradle sync 
`android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=false`

Comment: thanks it worked. now its showing this error Manifest merger failed : Attribute provider#com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider@authorities value=(fintnessathome.cardioexcercise.firebaseinitprovider) from AndroidManifest.xml:766:13-86
 is also present at [com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-72 value=(com.fintnessathome.fintnessathomeapp.firebaseinitprovider).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to <provider> element at AndroidManifest.xml:764:9-768:39 to override.

Comment: add `tools:replace="android:supportsRtl,android:allowBackup,icon,label">` in the application tag  into your manifest file and rerun the application

Comment: I have also updated the answer you can upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following Code in your manifest.xml

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
```

Comment: after adding following in gradle.properties file

android.useAndroidX=true 
android.enableJetifier=true  

its shows following error
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
   > Cannot parse project property android.useAndroidX='true ' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false'.